# Data structure for making decisions on multiple conditions

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, decision-tree

I have an XML mapping file with this structure:

```
<mappings>
    <mapping path="first">
        <parameter name="client_identifier">value1</parameter>
        <parameter name="device_identifier">value2</parameter>
        <parameter name="network_identifier">value3</parameter>
    </mapping>
    <mapping path="second">
        <parameter name="client_identifier">value1</parameter>
        <parameter name="device_identifier">value2</parameter>
        <parameter name="network_identifier">value4</parameter>
    </mapping>
    <mapping path="third">
        <parameter name="client_identifier">value1</parameter>
        <parameter name="device_identifier">value2</parameter>
    </mapping>
    <!-- hundreds/thousands more -->
</mappings>
```

Clients make requests to my application and based on some parameters contained in their requests I return some files. My mapping file above maps the parameters to the correct files. The `path` attribute in the `mapping` element is a file path to a directory containing those files.

I parse the file from top to bottom, operating on one mapping at a time, O(n) worst case. If all the parameters in that `<mapping>` match the ones in the client request, I return the directory value in `path`.

Example Client request

```
client_identifier = value1
device_identifier = value2
network_identifier = value10213

The third mapping with path=third will be returned because the other mappings don't match network_identifier.
```

Because this file can grow to a huge number of mappings because of all the possible combinations I was wondering if there was some data structure (decision tree) that might be faster to parse/compare.

The file itself has to keep the same structure, but I can parse it and create a different structure in memory.

Comment: This is not the case (and thus a comment and not an answer), but for a binary conditions one can use a [Binary Decision Diagram (BDD)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_decision_diagram) - which is better both in time and space then a decision tree. Of course you can enumerate the files, and then use log(M) different BDDs, but I doubt it is a good solution.

Comment: It's not a binary decision though, I have to match up parameters. For BDD, I'd have to make one for each client, device, network, and all other identifiers. It would become ridiculously big structure.

Comment: Yeap, as I said - it is not the case. Just linking the DS so you (or other readers) might get ideas and think of a modification that fits here. If it was an answer, I'd post it as such.

Comment: Couldn't you also keep the data structure in memory on the server side and use some hashing or dictionary indexing scheme to access the proper mapping in O(log(n)) time?

Comment: Yes, I'd have a map within a map within a map, ad nauseum. The parameters we have can change and this might not be manageable with nested hashes.

Comment: Maybe it could be turned into a relational database, and subjected to database indexing and optimization techniques. The input would be used to fill in the parameters in a prepared statement of the general form "select path from tablename where client=? and device=?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact what you describe is not an example of decision tree. Still there are some ways you can optimize your process. I would advice you to compute some kind of hash value for the attribute set in each mapping. For unset attributes add another "fake" value that means "unset".
After that iterate over the file and compare the hash computed for the query's attribute set to the hash of the attribute set of each mapping in a row. Only compare attributes if the hashes are the same(to avoid collision problems). This approach should speed comparisons significantly.

You can further improve the above approach - create a hash map between hash codes and the mappings that have this hash code. Don't to keep the mappings for a hash code in the same order as found in the file! After that you will only iterate over the mappings that have the same hash code and in the perfect case where no collisions happen this will be as good as you can get.